# Blackberry - run a JAD file on the simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have a jad file for a BB app which I want to run on the simulator. When I do a "Load Java Program" it looks for a cod file.

How can I run a JAD file on a BB simulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the BlackBerry browser, enter the web link to the JAD file in there and your application will be installed on your BlackBerry simulator.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work for me. The browser downloads the file and then I get a message that says "Unable to find default app". Also posted this problem on Black Berry Dev Forums @ http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Testing-a-PhoneGap-App-on-Simulator/td-p/1704247

Answer (score 1):

A JAD file is an information file that goes with the COD file that has the software. You should be able to get the COD file from the same place you got the JAD.

Comment: I am downloading the jad from an internet location. The cod file is not there. Is there any way to load a jad file into the simulator to run the application?

Comment: Open the JAD in a text editor. There will be a value called RIM-COD-URL that gives the location of the COD relative to the JAD. They are usually, but not always, in the same directory.

Comment: I got the RIM-COD-URL but the file downloaded from there gives me a RuntimeException.

Comment: OK, what does this application do? Not all functions of the device are supported in the simulator.

Comment: There may also be multiple COD files listed in the JAD, so make sure you have all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I have a jad file for a BB app which I want to run on the simulator. When I do a "Load Java Program" it looks for a cod file.

Comment: Jads are for OTA installation. You will have to use a cod when doing load java program.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) who finds they are presented with a .jad file only, but no .cod files, you need to...

1. look at this file in notepad as it will list the names of all the .cod files you need (maybe 40 to 50 of them)
2. notice the .jad file was located at `http://s3.amazonaws.com/blackberry.phonegap/slicehost-production/apps/123456/YourAppName.jad` so change the last bit of your own URL to `.cod` (or `-1.cod` and so on) to download the 40+ other files to the same folder
3. in the simulator, select File > Load and then multi-select **all** the .cod files together
4. wait patiently and your app will appear at the bottom of the simulated screen's menu