# Blackberry simulator won't load cod file from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I've got eclipse installed with the appropriate blackberry plug-ins, etc.  I can build the project fine.  When I try to debug using the simulator, the cod file is placed into the simulator's directory and the simulator starts, but I can't find the application.  It is not in the Downloads directory-thingy or anywhere else that I can see...

How do you tell fledge to load a particular cod?

I've tried all of the "solutions" in these 2, [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788442/application-not-getting-deployed-on-blackberry-simulator) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766870/blackberry-run-a-jad-file-on-the-simulator), but have had no success.

Comment: You can also try to [clean simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648800/how-to-remove-installed-java-programs-on-the-simulator)

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried that a few times with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had apparently done something that made the cod file invalid.  As such, it wouldn't load into the simulators.  In this particular case, a resource file had a space in it's name.

Comment: How did you determine the COD file was invalid?

Comment: Experimentation. I started deleting stuff until it worked then added back until it didn't.

Comment: Deleting all files with the name of your project might resolve the issue. As with many things in the BlackBerry dev environment, it's hit and miss.

Comment: Having a period `.` in the output `.cod` file caused this for me.