# application wont start or load in blackberry simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I'm developing an application on two different machines (home and work) and while the home one seems to run just fine, the work one is, for lack of a better word, possessed. It has been exhibiting the following issues:

- When loading the application, it will start at the simulator's main screen instead of starting the application at random intervals. You can start the application and have it work fine, then close the simulator, reload, and have the same codebase not load.
- Going to applications doesn't show the application itself, in fact it never does.
- Trying to load the applications cod file (File->load java program) never works. Tried the steps in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717912/blackberry-simulator-wont-load-cod-file-from-eclipse), with unreliable results.
- Extremely small changes, such as modifying the value of a width variable by one, commenting out a function such as makeMenu or adding a button will cause code to no longer work, with no errors shown by the IDE.
- Using clear.bat with sometimes work, sometimes not. Same with manually removing all files with the name of the project.
- reinstalling the eclipse environment and the blackberry plugin did nothing more then burn off an hour.
- having "load on startup" in the blackberry_app_descriptor.xml file is set.

Both systems are using Eclipse 3.5.1, BB plugin for eclipse 1.1 beta, Java 4.5 with the 8300 simulator. THe only difference that I am seeing is the operating system between the two systems. The work one being XP Sp3, home being vista. THe vista one isn't perfect, but I can test variable changes without flipping a coin to see if the app will even load or not.

I've tried the solutions that were similar on this forum, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788442/application-not-getting-deployed-on-blackberry-simulator), but it looked to be that those solutions are dated as none of the options for the steps existed in my eclipse install.

So has anyone ran into such baffling behavior, and can it be fixed? Anything that I might have missed that could be tried?

Comment: Have you tried other simulators?  It might just be that the one you're using is a little buggy.

Comment: Is there any errors in eclipse console during build? Are project files in simulator folder up to date? "none of the options for the steps existed in eclipse" - can you describe more specific?

Comment: @marc - Gave the 8100, the 8330, the 8300, and the 8700 with v4.5, and the 9000 with 4.6 a go, and all exhibited the same issues.

Comment: @max - When starting I ran it in debug, and no errors appeared in the console. The project files in the simulator folder, if I am understanding you correctly, were created when running the app for the first time after a clean.bat operation. For the "none of the options" mentioned in my original post, I'll update it to link to the other threads I found on stackoverflow that referenced similar issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been seeing this behavior with the new 1.1 plugin, the application doesn't load on startup and the FIle->load java program doesn't help. For me, the solution was I have to run a clean build every time, that is the eclipse clean and build instead of just build, not the clean.bat... Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how would this be done, and would it need to be done before loading the application into the simulator, or just once on loading eclipse for the first time.

Comment: If you go into Project -> Clean... Check the _Start a build immediately_ checkbox so it will also build after the clean and click ok. After it builds run the simulator. 

BTW, for me the application shows up under the downloads folder, not the applications folder, it depends on the setting in the app desscriptor.

Comment: That seems to work, although before executing clean needs to be ran or else unpredictable behavior occurs. Is this similar to what you found? As for location it might be the simulator. I've found the newer ones will have the app in downloads instead of applications.

Comment: Yes, I run _clean_ every time before I execute, but only if something changed in code, if the code did not change between simulator runs, there's no need to do a clean build. Some of my coworkers have seen this behavior as well with the 1.1 plugin: if a clean build is not preformed before execution, the program will not always load, and even an explicit load from the simulator will not help. I'm glad it worked!  :)

Comment: Yep. Just wish it would run clean when you hit execute for the application. Maybe for 1.2? :D

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing resources that have improper naming structure in your projects stuff with spaces or special character in the name of the file.

It took me two days to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

One solution i got regarding your problem.
As I See Please run the  application first time as Run as blackberry simulator
that is got start and here pick up run and then Run as Blackberry simulator