# Blackberry application loading on simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

while loading my application on BlackBerry simulator its displaying given below an error

> Unable to start simulator.  Check that the file exists.  (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments)

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518856/application-wont-start-or-load-in-blackberry-simulator?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue whilst trying to run the demo application.

I am running Windows 7 Professional,JDK 7u21 and STS 3.2.

This is an issue with the changes made to the decoding of command strings specified to Runtime.exec method.

In summary the path configured for the simulator launch contains spaces.In my case "C:\Program Files (x86)"

To Fix this issue

1. Copy the simulator Dir and MDS to a new directory that has no spaces.
2. From the run configuration settings,enable the use of Customized Command line ,Customized  Working directory and Customized  MDS directory.Update the
           entries to point to the new path that has no spaces.

Alternatively you can use windows shortened dir name by typing dir /X in the CMD from the directory that contains the simulator and MDS,this should give you something like PROGRAM~2

In the end ,the issue is not with the IDE or the Simulator,just java and windows not playing nice.

see [Oracle JDK 7u21 release note](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html#jruntime)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

1. Go to debugger Configurations, Simulator, Advanced and COPY the "default command line".
2. Hit debug. When the alert with the error appears:
3. Open a shell/cmd and paste the text obtained in step 1, hit enter.
4. It should open the emulator an the debugger should attached without a problem.

This is not an error, this is an "upgrade" of Oracle Java due to security issues, you cannot longer execute commandlines with arguments if theyre not passed as an array..

Hope it helps.

Also:

Here is the error documentated:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html#jruntime

Heres the patch but only for java 17 and earlier:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/javacpuapr2013-1928497.html

Answer (score 0):

remove the Java 7 and keep only the java 6 and it will work fine 
i have the same issue and i solve it with the above solution